# Please give the latex code for this diagram, with the shaded region as shown

Tags: tikz-pgf, shapes

[image]

I have could draw the diagram except the shaded region and the marks showing that OP and OP' are equal. Please help me out!!

Comment: Please post the code you have so far for the above picture.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Too bad this post is no longer accepting answers, because I had a very nice solution in `tkz-euclide` to give ;)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another tikz solution. This uses `calc` library for drawing some coordinates and the equal marks. Ovbiously, it needs the `patterns` library too.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25,line join=round]
% coordinates
\coordinate (O)  at (0,0);
\coordinate (O') at ({3*sqrt(2)},0);
\coordinate (T)  at ({sqrt(2)},0);
\coordinate (P)  at ({1.5*sqrt(2)},{sqrt(3.5)});
\coordinate (M)  at ($(O) !0.4!(P)$); % blue mark
\coordinate (N)  at ($(O')!0.4!(P)$); % blue mark
% shaded region
\fill[pattern=north west lines,pattern color=red] (O) -- (O') -- (P) -- cycle;
% circles
\draw[fill=white]  (O)  circle ({sqrt(2)});
\draw[fill=white]  (O') circle ({2*sqrt(2)});
\draw[gray,dashed] ($(P)-({2*sqrt(2)},0)$) arc (180:360:{2*sqrt(2)});
% triangle and blue marks
\draw (O) -- (O') -- (P) -- cycle;
\draw[blue,thick] ($(M)!0.15cm!270:(P)$) -- ($(M)!0.15cm!90:(P)$);
\draw[blue,thick] ($(N)!0.15cm!270:(P)$) -- ($(N)!0.15cm!90:(P)$);
% points and nodes
\fill (O)  circle (1pt) node [below] {$O$};
\fill (O') circle (1pt) node [below] {$O'$};
\fill (T)  circle (1pt);
\fill (P)  circle (1pt) node [above] {$P$};
\node at ($(O)!0.5!(T)$)  [below] {$\sqrt{2}$};
\node at ($(T)!0.5!(O')$) [below] {$2\sqrt{2}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can draw the filled region with a combination of an `even odd rule`d path inside a `clip`ped `scope`. For details please have a look at the comments in the code.

To add the Labels is really easy/basic which you should be able to do on your own. If not, have a look at the tutorials in TikZ's manual (pgfmanual.pdf).

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
    % (for debugging purposes only)
    \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % (so we don't have to repeat the coordinates over and over again)
    \coordinate (A) at (0,-1);
    \coordinate (B) at (4.9,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (2.65,2);

    % (create some "abbreviations for the pathes)
    \newcommand{\Triangle}{(A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle}
    \newcommand{\CircleA}{(A) circle [radius=2]}
    \newcommand{\CircleB}{(B) circle [radius=3]}

    % draw the stuff
    \draw
        \Triangle
        \CircleA
        \CircleB
    ;

    % draw the filling
    \begin{scope}
        \clip \Triangle;

        \fill[
            even odd rule,
            gray,
        ]
            \Triangle
            \CircleA
            \CircleB
        ;
    \end{scope}

    % -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % for debugging purposes to prove that no white filling is needed
    \begin{scope}[on background layer={color=yellow}]
        \fill (current bounding box.south west)
            rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
    \end{scope}
    % -------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: +1 for your simple solution and yet no white filling required (unlike in my code). I'd have to take a look at the `even odd rule`. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @owmal, you are welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an approach using [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) wrapped up in `luamplib`.  You need to compile this with `lualatex`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    path c, c';
    c = fullcircle scaled 144;
    c' = c scaled 2; c' := c' shifted (point 0 of c - point 4 of c');

    numeric t, u;
    (t, whatever) = c' intersectiontimes c' shifted - center c';
    (u, whatever) = c intersectiontimes (center c -- point t of c');

    path s;
    s = subpath (0, u) of c -- subpath (t, 4) of c' -- cycle;

    % leave this out if you do not want the shade in region s
    for i=0 upto 50:
        draw (left--right) scaled 200 rotated 135 shifted (4i, 0) withcolor 1/2[blue, white];
    endfor
    clip currentpicture to s;

    draw c' shifted (point t of c' - center c') withcolor 15/16;

    draw c  withcolor 2/3 blue;
    draw c' withcolor 2/3 blue;
    draw center c -- center c' -- point t of c' -- cycle;

    dotlabel.llft("$O$", center c);
    dotlabel.lrt("$O'$", center c');
    dotlabel.ulft("$P$", point t of c');

    label.bot("$\sqrt2$", 1/2[center c, point 0 of c]);
    label.bot("$2\sqrt2$", 1/2[center c', point 4 of c']);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your question is only about the shaded space and not about exact dimensions, labeling, etc., I have a possible solution.

You can do this by using the `tikz` library. My approach would be making the triangle completely filled with patterns and then use `\clip` to fill the spaces of the triangle where there is intersection with the circles in white color.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    % Draw triangle completely filled with patterns
    \draw[pattern=north west lines] (0,-1) -- (4.9, 0) -- (2.65, 2) -- (0,-1);
    
    % Remove patterns inside left circle and draw left circle
    \begin{scope}
        \clip (0,-1) circle (2);
        \draw[fill=white] (0,-1) -- (4.9, 0) -- (2.65, 2) -- (0,-1);
    \end{scope}
    
    \draw (0,-1) circle (2);
    
    % Remove patterns inside right circle and draw right circle
    \begin{scope}
        \clip (4.9,0) circle (3);
        \draw[fill=white] (0,-1) -- (4.9, 0) -- (2.65, 2) -- (0,-1);
    \end{scope}
    
    \draw (4.9,0) circle (3);
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```